# error confusion when calling hyperref and minitoc package

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, minitoc

I have a report where I need to use links, when I call the package `hyperref` I got an error on 18 lines which are correctly compiled when I remove the calling command, the lines are in a chapter in another document which is included at the main one.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,francais]{babel}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref} %this line is causing the error
\begin{document}
\include{chapitres/Formats}
\end{document}
```

the chapter included begin like this

```
\chapter{Formats de textes et paragraphes}
\minitoc %for mini tableofcontent
\newpage
```

here is a part of the error code, all the lines are correct when I remove the `hyperref` package.

[image]

Comment: Try to add the `minitoc` package. And `%` is the latex comment symbol, not two backslashed.

Comment: I'm calling the minitoc package after hyperref. sorry for the comment symbol (java habit ^_^)

Comment: if you add or remove hyperref the format of internal commands change, and you often need to remove .toc and other intermediate files.

Comment: I removed all other files and recompile, it doesn't generate any error but the minitoc have desepeared

Comment: Probably, there is a mixture of auxiliary files (`.aux`, `.toc`), which are generated with and without `hyperref`. Remove all auxiliary files and try again, because `hyperref` changes some internals in the auxiliary files.

Comment: I've done that 2 times, same result, the mini table of content doesn't appear, I compiled with bibtex and nothing, the main table of content appears but the mini one not

Comment: you need to run latex at least twice to generate the minitoc

Comment: please post the error you get _from the posted code_.

Comment: the error caused by hyperref is solved when I removed auxiliary files, but now the minitoc doesn't appear

Comment: the example chapter you posted has no sections so what minitoc do you expect?

Comment: I removed the hyperref and the minitoc still not shown up

Comment: the code is large I can't post it all but I do have sections, and the minitoc was fine before the hyperref problem

Comment: As has been explained in your previous questions you do not need to post a large document. Post a small document that shows the error. Fix the example above so that  it does not make a minitoc when you think it should, and delete the large screenshot of errors from a different document which is not helpful at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44323/discussion-between-hind-dev-and-david-carlisle).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `minitoc` package requires some more setup than just using `\usepackage{minitoc}`.

- `\dominitoc` to make LaTeX aware that it should generate code for the chapterwise `ToC`
- `\tableofcontents` or `\faketableofcontents`
- Without using `\section` etc. after `minitoc` will do **nothing**

---

More subtle setups require reading the very voluminous manual of `minitoc`, however.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,francais]{babel}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref} %this line is causing the error
\dominitoc

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Formats de textes et paragraphes}
\minitoc %for mini tableofcontent
\section{Foo}
%\include{chapitres/Formats}
\end{document}
```

The code works with `\include{....}` as well.

[image]

Comment: thank you @Christian Hupfer I found the error, I had to call hyperref between usepackage minitoc and \dominitoc, like you did, I didn't knew that the way we call packages count on Latex